# Python interfacing with C library - How to have a null c pointer

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have the following old c code.

```
const char *c[3];
c[0] = "ABC";
c[1] = "EFG";
c[2] = 0;
c_function(c);
```

Now, I need to use Python to call old c function. I have the following code.

```
c_names = (c_char_p * 3)()
c_names[0] = "ABC";
c_names[1] = "EFG";
// c[2] = 0??
libc = CDLL("c_library.dll")
libc.c_function(c_names)
```

May I know what is the Python equivalent for `c[2] = 0;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` and `0` both work:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> x=ctypes.c_char_p(0)
>>> x
c_char_p(None)
>>> x=ctypes.c_char_p(None)
>>> x
c_char_p(None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pointer = None
```

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

check 15.16.1.3. Calling functions